# C++ Reference being duplicated when generated in loop at runtime

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, sfml

I have recently switched from C# to C++ trying to learn SFML for graphical animation.

I am trying to generate multiple CircleShape with random radius at runtime whose reference is saved as an object class, whose reference is then saved in a vector array.

However, after generating the shapes and iterating through the array to draw the shapes from the vector array, it seems that all of them are references to the same shape.

My Code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

template <class T>
class Entity {
    T* m_shape;
    
public:
    Entity(T* shape)
    {
        m_shape = shape;
    }

    T* getShape() {
        return m_shape;
    }
};

class ShapesManager {
    std::vector<Entity<sf::CircleShape*>*>* circleShape;

public:
    ShapesManager()
    {
        circleShape = new std::vector<Entity<sf::CircleShape*>*>();
    }

    std::vector<Entity<sf::CircleShape*>*>* getCircleShapes() 
    {
        return circleShape;
    }

    void addCircleShape(Entity<sf::CircleShape*>* EntityToAdd) {
        circleShape->push_back(EntityToAdd);
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int windowWidth = 800;
    const int windowHeight = 600;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "SFML works!");
    //window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    ShapesManager m_entityManager;

    int lowSize = 25;
    int highSize = 80;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        srand(i + 5732 + (i * 524));

        float circleRadius = lowSize + static_cast<float>(rand()) * static_cast<float>(highSize - lowSize) / RAND_MAX;

        sf::CircleShape* someValue = new sf::CircleShape(circleRadius);
        (*someValue).setPosition((circleRadius * 2), (circleRadius * 2));
        Entity<sf::CircleShape*>* myObj = new Entity<sf::CircleShape*>(&someValue);
        m_entityManager.addCircleShape(myObj);
    }

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();

        for (Entity<sf::CircleShape*>* cE : ((std::vector<Entity<sf::CircleShape*>*>)* m_entityManager.getCircleShapes())) {
            Entity<sf::CircleShape*> myCircleEntity = *cE;
            sf::CircleShape* cS = *myCircleEntity.getShape();
            window.draw((*cS));
        }

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have gone through my code multiple times to make sure I am not referencing a single shape for all other shapes.

*I have come across "Shared Pointers/Unique Pointers" while trying to search for a solution, though I have yet to get the grasp of it, but if that is what I should be using to help overcome my issue, make sure to mention it in comments as I am looking more for knowledge than a direct solution.

Comment: There's no need for `circleShape` to be a pointer, just make it a normal member variable

Comment: Your problem is presumably `&someValue` being a pointer to a local variable, when `someValue` goes out of scope the pointer becomes invalid. The compiler will likely then reuse the same memory address for the next iteration of the loop giving you lots of invalid pointers all with the same value. Presumably you meant to use `Entity<sf::CircleShape>(someValue)`

Comment: First, you're not actually using C++ references - you're using pointers.  Although there is a relationship between them, they are actually quite distinct things in C++.   Second (possibly related comment) it appears you are thinking about C++ pointers as if they work like C# references - which they are not.  In fact, C# references are somewhat different to C++ references or C++ pointers (they have some properties of both, but also differences from both).

Comment: @AlanBirtles That completely makes sense, I had only the scope of the function itself in my mind and not the loop.

Comment: @Peter yup even though I started learning about C++ just a few days ago, I can see alot of difference between things that does exist on C# too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @AlanBirtles is right. On each iteration `new sf::CircleShape(circleRadius);` allocates new memory, so the pointer `someValue` will point to the different memory addresses each time. You can't say the same about the memory address of the `someValue` itself, in your case it seems that the pointer `someValue` is created in the same memory address on each iteration, that's why taking a reference to this pointer returns the same value on each iteration.

The solutions @AlanBirtles suggested should be enough.